# How to i style the elements from the TinyMCE

Tags: theme-development, css, tinymce

if i have a paragraph  with class "test" in the TinyMCE editor how do i style the paragraph using my style.css file in my theme or do i need to make a separate file and if so how would i go about that?
By the way i can see the style i apply from the style.css file when i go to the visual TinyMCE editor but not when i preview the page

Comment: `p.test { /* CSS code */ }`?

Comment: https://codex.wordpress.org/TinyMCE_Custom_Styles

Answer (score 2):

You can use the custom CSS field in the customizer if your theme supports it. Or you will have to create a child theme and add the custom css to your child theme's stylesheet.

Comment: So i can't just  style the paragraph using the style.css file?

Comment: If you are not using a child theme any custom css will be wiped out if you update the theme.

Answer (score 1):

The class that you assign the the paragraph is key to your styles.

in your style.css (hopefully it's a child theme)

Just add

```
.test {
  color: blue;
}
```

or what ever property you're trying to change.

Comment: Would it work without a child theme

Comment: Same way, but if you ever decide to update your theme the changes in your stylesheet.css will be overwritten.

Answer (score 1):

WordPress has a feature called [editor styles](https://codex.wordpress.org/Editor_Style).

To use them, simply call `add_editor_style()` in your theme's functions.php file and add a new `editor-style.css` file. This will be picked up inside the TinyMCE editor to style content.

Use something like `add_editor_style( 'css/custom-editor-style.css' );` if you want to use a different file (like your existing `style.css` for example).